# Add pip requirements to docker image in runtime

Tags: python, docker, pip, requirements.txt

I want to be able to add some extra requirements to an own create docker image. My strategy is build the image from a dockerfile with a CMD command that will execute a "pip install -r" command using a mounted volume in runtime.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /root

CMD ["pip install -r /root/sourceCode/requirements.txt"]
```

Having that dockerfile I build the image:

```
sudo docker build -t test .
```

And finally I try to attach my new requirements using this command:

```
sudo docker run -v $(pwd)/sourceCode:/root/sourceCode -it test /bin/bash
```

My local folder "sourceCode" has inside a valid requirements.txt file (it contains only one line with the value "gunicorn"). 
When I get the prompt I can see that the requirements file is there, but if I execute a pip freeze command the gunicorn package is not listed.

Why the requirements.txt file is been attached correctly but the pip command is not working properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TLDR

`pip` command isn't running because you are telling Docker to run `/bin/bash` instead.

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/sourceCode:/root/sourceCode -it test /bin/bash
                                                              ^
                                                             here
```

#### Longer explanation

The default `ENTRYPOINT` for a container is `/bin/sh -c`. You don't override that in the Dockerfile, so that remains. The default `CMD` instruction is probably nothing. You do override that in your Dockerfile. When you run *(ignore the volume for brevity)*

```
docker run -it test
```

what actually executes inside the container is

```
/bin/sh -c pip install -r /root/sourceCode/requirements.txt
```

Pretty straight forward, looks like it will run `pip` when you start the container.

Now let's take a look at the command you used to start the container *(again, ignoring volumes)*

```
docker run -v -it test /bin/bash
```

what actually executes inside the container is

```
/bin/sh -c /bin/bash
```

the `CMD` arguments you specified in your Dockerfile get overridden by the `COMMAND` you specify in the command line. Recall that `docker run` [command takes this form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

#### Further reading

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile/34245657#34245657) has a really to the point explanation of what `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions do

   > The `ENTRYPOINT` specifies a command that will always be executed when the container starts.
   >
   > The `CMD` specifies arguments that will be fed to the `ENTRYPOINT`.
2. This [blog post](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/) on the difference between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions that's worth reading.

Comment: Thx @ROMANARMY for the long explanation....I think that now I've understand better the way that docker can receive parameters in runtime.

Answer (score 7):

You may change the last statement i.e., `CMD` to below.

--specify absolute path of pip location in below statement

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/pip", "install", "-r", "/root/sourceCode/requirements.txt"]
```

**UPDATE:** adding additional answer based on comments.

One thing must be noted that, if customized image is needed with additional requirements, that should part of the image rather than doing at run time.

Using below base image to test:

```
docker pull colstrom/python:legacy
```

So, installing packages should be run using `RUN` command of Dockerfile.
And `CMD` should be used what app you actually wanted to run as a process inside of container.

Just checking if the base image has any pip packages by running below command and results **nothing**.

```
docker run --rm --name=testpy colstrom/python:legacy /usr/bin/pip freeze
```

*Here is simple example to demonstrate the same:*

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM colstrom/python:legacy
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN ["/usr/bin/pip", "install", "-r", "/requirements.txt"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/pip", "freeze"]
```

**requirements.txt**

```
selenium
```

**Build the image with pip packages** Hope you know to place Dockerfile, requirements.txt file in fresh directory.

```
D:\dockers\py1>docker build -t pypiptest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM colstrom/python:legacy
 ---> 640409fadf3d
Step 2 : COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 ---> abbe03846376
Removing intermediate container c883642f06fb
Step 3 : RUN /usr/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 1987b5d47171
Collecting selenium (from -r /requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading selenium-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (913kB)
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.0.1
 ---> f0bc90e6ac94
Removing intermediate container 1987b5d47171
Step 4 : CMD /usr/bin/pip freeze
 ---> Running in 6c3435177a37
 ---> dc1925a4f36d
Removing intermediate container 6c3435177a37
Successfully built dc1925a4f36d
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

**Now run the image**
If you are not passing any external command, then container takes command from `CMD` which is just shows the list of `pip` packages. Here in this case, `selenium`.

```
D:\dockers\py1>docker run -itd --name testreq pypiptest
039972151eedbe388b50b2b4cd16af37b94e6d70febbcb5897ee58ef545b1435

D:\dockers\py1>docker logs testreq
selenium==3.0.1
```

So, the above shows that package is installed successfully.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Rao but this change doesn't produce any result. After running the new image, gunicorn is still not among the packages showed by pip freeze.

Comment: I have also notice that if I run the image without the -it /bin/bash options `sudo docker run -v $(pwd)/sourceCode:/root/sourceCode test` the console raises the following message `Downloading/unpacking gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r /root/sourceCode/requirements.txt (line 1))
Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Compiling /tmp/pip_build_root/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/_gaiohttp.py ...
  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/_gaiohttp.py", line 84
    yield from self.wsgi.close()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed gunicorn
Cleaning up...`

Comment: Although CMD syntax is likely incorrect, it's likely not an issue because it's being overriden from command line anyway.

Comment: @ralvarez, may be you want to check the updated answer and see that is more understanable?

Comment: Thx for the long explanation @Rao but the ability of adding requirements at runtime is a "must" for my client. Anyway your answer has been very useful for me as now I understand a little better the CMD command and also the `docker logs` command.

Comment: I am sure there must be some application or process be running in the container, and container is not used for just fulfilling the requirements. Hence, the requirements should be part of the image and you should pass the different application while running the container. If you think the answer is useful, you may consider up vote or accepting it as answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the concepts that @Rao and @ROMANARMY have explained in their answers, I find out finally a way of doing what I wanted: add extra python requirements to a self-created docker image.

My new Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /root

COPY install_req.sh .

CMD ["/bin/bash" , "install_req.sh"]
```

I've added as first command the execution of a shell script that has the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install -r /root/sourceCode/requirements.txt
pip freeze > /root/sourceCode/freeze.txt
```

And finally I build and run the image using these commands:

```
docker build --tag test .
docker run -itd --name container_test -v $(pwd)/sourceCode:/root/sourceCode test <- without any parameter at the end
```

As I explained at the beginning of the post, I have in a local folder a folder named sourceCode that contains a valid requirements.txt file with only one line "gunicorn"

So finally I've the ability of adding some extra requirements (gunicorn package in this example) to a given docker image.

After building and running my experiment If I check the logs (`docker logs container_test`) I see something like this:

```
Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
    100% |################################| 122kB 1.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: gunicorn
```

Furthermore, the container have created a freeze.txt file inside the mounted volume that contains all the pip packages installed, including the desired gunicorn:

```
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
gunicorn==19.6.0
html5lib==0.999
requests==2.2.1
six==1.5.2
urllib3==1.7.1
```

Now I've other problems with the permissions of the new created file, but that will be probably in a new post.

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, Rao's suggestion to build the requirements into the image is a good one. Building images is pretty fast. Docker also does layer caching, so if the requirements file doesn't change it won't have to re-run that step. That makes building new images even faster. That's the approach described [here](https://medium.com/@fbzga/how-to-cache-bundle-install-with-docker-7bed453a5800#efe7). Although the article is about rails, it addresses the same concern, managing dependencies.