# Docker image with Python 2.7, PIP and Standard libs

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I'm looking for a docker image that contains python 2.7, Standard libs, and pip installed. (exactly what you got when installing Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04). I've tried various version of python and Ubuntu on docker hub.
Any one has an idea or a lead how to do this ?

Comment: what do you call "standard libs"? Pymongo, fabric, fabtools, PyGTK, WxPython, Kivy, Pyside, chardet, NLTK... should be included?

Comment: libs that comes with a fresh Ubuntu install, **requests** for instance

Comment: you could also start with a minimal Python image like https://github.com/elyase/docker/tree/master/conda and add whatever suits you. This image is available for Python 2.7 and 3.4, by the way. I found it reading http://yasermartinez.com/blog/posts/creating-super-small-docker-images.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`colstrom/python:legacy`](https://hub.docker.com/r/colstrom/python/) is the right image that may help your need.

```
$ docker search colstrom/python
NAME              DESCRIPTION                   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
colstrom/python   Docker on Python, with pip!   1                    [OK]
```

Even if some library is missed, it can be fulfilled as part of your customized images as explained an example privided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534274/add-pip-requirements-to-docker-image-in-runtime/40534935#40534935)